# wordpress useState do not updateding the view after removing the elemnt

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

```
export default function Edit(props) {
    // https://dev.to/collegewap/how-to-delete-an-item-from-the-state-array-in-react-kl

    const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
    const { imagesIds, author } = attributes;

    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getImagesIds();
    }, []);

    function selectImages(media) {
        let imagesArr = []; // used to store as image array
        Array.from(media).forEach(function (ele, key) {
            imagesArr[key] = { id: ele["id"], url: ele["url"] };
        });
        setImages(imagesArr);
    }

    function removeImage(e) {
        console.log("* removeImage *");

        let li = getParentByTagName(e.target, "li");
        if (li !== null && li !== undefined && typeof li === "object") {
            console.log(images);
            let id = li.getAttribute("data-index");

            images.splice(id, 1);
            setImages(images);
            console.log(images);

            // this removeImage function is not updating the view
        }
    }

    function getImagesIds() {
        let imagesIdsArr = [];
        Array.from(images).forEach(function (image, key) {
            imagesIdsArr[key] = image["id"];
        });
        setAttributes({ imagesIds: imagesIdsArr });
    }

    function getParentByTagName(element, tagName) {
        tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
        while (element.parentNode) {
            element = element.parentNode;

            if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === tagName) {
                return element;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    return (
        <>
            {images !== null && images.length > 0 && (
                <ul style={{ maxWidth: "100%", padding: 0 }}>
                    {images.map((image, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li
                                key={index}
                                data-id={image["id"]}
                                data-index={index}
                                style={{
                                    display: "inline-block",
                                    padding: "10px",
                                    position: "relative",
                                }}
                            >
                                <img src={image["url"]} style={{ maxWidth: 200 }} />
                                <span
                                    onClick={removeImage}
                                    style={{
                                        position: "absolute",
                                        top: "0px",
                                        right: "0px",
                                        background: "#ddd",
                                        padding: "2px 4px",
                                        borderRadius: "5px",
                                        cursor: "pointer",
                                    }}
                                >
                                    Remove
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
            )}

            <MediaUploadCheck>
                <MediaUpload
                    multiple={true}
                    title={"Please select images for slider"}
                    modalClass={"modalClassForAdmin"}
                    allowedTypes={ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES}
                    addToGallery={false}
                    gallery={false}
                    value={imagesIds}
                    onSelect={(media) => selectImages(media)}
                    render={({ open }) => (
                        <Button onClick={open}>Please select images for slider</Button>
                    )}
                />
            </MediaUploadCheck>
        </>
    );
}
```

I am trying to create images selector module using React. When I selected the images, I am unable to remove any image using `removeImage` function. I have used the 'images' in the state but when I am calling the `removeImage` function, it is not updating the view.